# Eclipse Plugin Development - how to set project baseline?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

Wanted to take a look at developing an Eclipse plugin.  Installed the Plugin Development Environment and created a new plugin project from the "Hello World" plugin template.

Initially I got an error that there was no API Baseline defined.  So, I went in to Preferences | Plug-in Development | API Baselines and defined one (based on the installation directory for my Eclipse, which is version 2020-06 so I called it "2020-06").  This is defined and is the default.

Now, the error has changed to

> There is a possible API baseline mismatch since none of the workspace
> projects is in the baseline.

I've googled and I can find many answers telling me how to turn the error off (or downgrade it to a warning).  But I can't find anything that says how I actually *fix* it.  How do I define the baseline for the project?  (I've close all other projects in my workspace and this is anyway my only plugin project)

It's currently an untouched "Hello World" plugin template so I assume it doesn't use APIs later that 2020-06 but if it is an actual problem, how do O find out what calls are causing it?  The message reads like a config missing on the project - if the code included an API call that breaks the baseline I'd expect a more specific error.

Comment: The error isn't about APIs that are called, it is about the contents of the baseline. This error was added fairly recently (see [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=538904)) I'm not sure I understand why it was added. For a first plugin I would not enable API analysis.

Comment: Did you read the [API Tools documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-06/nav/4_2_3)?

Comment: @howlger When I tried following the doc I got exactly the same error. This seems to be something that has to be turned off